# Dynamic Variables Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

to improve my skills I am currently creating a file, which should track a game of dart. The users write their throws in a cell and add this value to a table.

Most of this already works but the logic behind changing players is not working yet.

I have the following code snippet set-up for the players:

```
Dim PlayerID As Object

Set PlayerID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To 3
    PlayerID(i) = Setupws.Range("C" & i)
    PlayerID(i) = Setupws.Range("C" & i).Value

Next i

Set GameTable = Gamews.ListObjects("GameTable")

Set NewRow = GameTable.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
    Lastrow = Gamews.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Beforerow = Gamews.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

With GameTable

 If .Range(Beforerow, 5).Value = 3 And .Range(Beforerow, 9).Value = 3 Then
        .Range(Lastrow, 3).Value = PlayerID.Value

        Else
        .Range(Lastrow, 3).Value = .Range(Beforerow, 3).Value

              End If
```

The Logic behind this is that if the value in the column 5 is at 3 (it cycles from 1 to 3) the next PlayerID is added to the table.

Basically:

PlayerID(1) Throw 1

PlayerID(1) Throw 2

PlayerID(1) Throw 3

PlayerID(2) Throw 1

etc.

I am getting a Run-Time error 438...

Error happens right here:

```
.Range(Lastrow, 3).Value = PlayerID.Value
```

Some ideas? I have not added the rest of the code where i define the sheets and other variables to my post, but can post it if it helps.

BR
Thomas

Comment: It makes it fairly difficult to read without proper indenting. Which line is the run-time error happening on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would expect from this `PlayerID.Value` This won't work with a dictionary. You'd need to reference it as `PlayerID(Key)` or `PlayerID.Items`

Comment: What is the point of a dictionary with keys 1,2,3 (whose value is set to the same value twice in a row since `PlayerID(i) = Setupws.Range("C" & i)` and `PlayerID(i) = Setupws.Range("C" & i).Value` are functionally the same)? If you want the keys to be 1,2,3 -- just use an array. If you want the keys to be something else, use the `Add` method of the dictionary object.